# The best way to naturally lower ph to 5.5

Tags: camellia

My pH is a steady 7.0
I'm organic and need to lower to 5.0-6.5 growing tea

Comment: I asked a similar question and got good suggestions here: https://forum.bonsaimirai.com/t/quick-method-of-acidifying-soil-for-blueberry/8133/19

Answer (score 1):

Difficult to give an answer you will like; 1 - move, or ,2- dig out and remove at least one foot of soil and replace it with sand and pine needle and oak leaf compost. As it happens ,that is what my soil is . My pH is about 6 so I grow camellias and azaleas. When I lived in IL with a pH 7.5 + soil , I wanted acid soil for blue berries. I tried several things ( mulch, gypsum , sulfur) with no success. As a last resort ,I put 1/2 L of concentrated sulfuric acid around each plant ( not for the average camper). Blue berries grew great for one year but adding acid each year is not practical.

Comment: I'm already on the way.. removed all to soil. In dealing with sand. I am experimenting with sulphur and "vinegar cider"also added lava rock?

Comment: You must really like tea. Aluminum sulfate I did not use but is acid.  Bone meal - adds phosphoric acid ( and calcium , etc).  For fertilizer try Jacks / Peters starter ; 9 - 45  - 15  , the 45 is more or less phosphoric . It is about the only fertilizer I use ; my soil is already acid so it doesn't make it worse and camellias and azaleas bloom well . I do not grow vegetables   I think camellias are related to tea, maybe I should grow tea..

Comment: Vinegar is acetic ; acidic, hydrochloric and nitric all make very water soluble compounds and then to wash through the soil . Sulfates and phosphates are less soluble and are retained better..